# FreeRtos , the higher priority task reacts the same as the lower priority ones

Tags: c, embedded, scheduled-tasks

The code creates 4 timers that control 4 semaphores with which the tasks will work when they take the semaphore. There are 3 sender tasks and 1 receiver, the sender sends to the queue that was created (first 2 senders are of same priority while the third is of higher priority) in a random period of time that is passed to the timer randomly using the random function. after the code reaches 1000 msgs, it resets with the bounds for the timer to send being higher, it goes through this for 6 cycles then it shuts down and stops the scheduler and prints game over the msg to be sent is "time is XYZ" where XYZ is the system time in ticks

```
/*
 * This file is part of the µOS++ distribution.
 *   (https://github.com/micro-os-plus)
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Liviu Ionescu.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
 * sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom
 * the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "diag/trace.h"
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION 1

/* Kernel includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "timers.h"
#include "semphr.h"
#include "projdefs.h"
#include "event_groups.h"
#include "portable.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "croutine.h"
#include "deprecated_definitions.h"
#include "mpu_prototypes.h"
#include "mpu_wrappers.h"
#include "StackMacros.h"
#include <time.h>
#define CCM_RAM __attribute__((section(".ccmram")))
int NumberOfSent1=0;
int NumberOfSent2=0;
int NumberOfSent3=0;
int NumberOfBlocked1=0;
int NumberOfBlocked2=0;
int NumberOfBlocked3=0;
int NumberOfReceived=0;
int Average_sent1=0;
int Average_sent2=0;
int Average_sent3=0;
int Average_blocked1=0;
int Average_blocked2=0;
int Average_blocked3=0;
int TotalTime1=0;
int TotalTime2=0;
int TotalTime3=0;
int Timer1Rand;
int Timer2Rand;
int Timer3Rand;
int UpperBound=150;
int LowerBound=50;
int TimeTask1=0;
int TimeTask2=0;
int TimeTask3=0;
short AverageTime1=0;
short AverageTime2=0;
short AverageTime3=0;
int counterForCycle=0;
char tickcount_converted[10];
char Message[30]="Time is ";
char Buffer[32];
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore1;
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore2;
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore3;
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore4;
QueueHandle_t GlobalQueue;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
 * The LED timer callback function.  This does nothing but switch the red LED
 * off.
 */

static void Timer1Callback( TimerHandle_t xTimer );
static void Timer2Callback( TimerHandle_t xTimer );
static void Timer3Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer);
void Timer4Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer);
static void Sender1(void);
static void Sender2(void);
static void Sender3(void);
void Receiver(void);

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* The LED software timer.  This uses vLEDTimerCallback() as its callback
 * function.
 */
static TimerHandle_t xTimer1;
static TimerHandle_t xTimer2;
static TimerHandle_t xTimer3;
static TimerHandle_t xTimer4;
TaskHandle_t Task1H;
TaskHandle_t Task2H;
TaskHandle_t Task3H;
TaskHandle_t Task4H;

BaseType_t Task1;
BaseType_t Task2;
BaseType_t Task3;
BaseType_t Task4;
BaseType_t xTimer1Started, xTimer2Started,xTimer3Started,xTimer4Started;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Semihosting STM32F4 empty sample (trace via DEBUG).
//
// Trace support is enabled by adding the TRACE macro definition.
// By default the trace messages are forwarded to the DEBUG output,
// but can be rerouted to any device or completely suppressed, by
// changing the definitions required in system/src/diag/trace-impl.c
// (currently OS_USE_TRACE_ITM, OS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG/_STDOUT).
//

// ----- main() ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Sample pragmas to cope with warnings. Please note the related line at
// the end of this function, used to pop the compiler diagnostics status.
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-declarations"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreturn-type"

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Add your code here.
    srand(time(NULL));
    xSemaphore1=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphore2=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphore3=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphore4=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphoreGive(xSemaphore4);
    GlobalQueue=xQueueCreate(3,32);
    Timer1Rand=(rand() % (150 - 50 + 1)) + 50;
    Timer2Rand=(rand() % (150 - 50 + 1)) + 50;
    Timer3Rand=(rand() % (150 - 50 + 1)) + 50;
    xTimer1 = xTimerCreate( "Timer1", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer1Rand) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 0, Timer1Callback);
    xTimer2 = xTimerCreate( "Timer2", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer2Rand) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 1, Timer2Callback);
    xTimer3 = xTimerCreate( "Timer3", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer3Rand) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 2, Timer3Callback);
    xTimer4 = xTimerCreate( "Timer4", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(100) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 3, Timer4Callback);
    Task1 = xTaskCreate(Sender1,"Sender1",1024,(void *)1,1,&Task1H);
    Task2 = xTaskCreate(Sender2,"Sender2",1024,(void *)2,1,&Task2H);
    Task3 = xTaskCreate(Sender3,"Sender3",1024,(void *)3,2,&Task3H);
    Task4 = xTaskCreate(Receiver,"Receiver",1024,(void *)4,3,&Task4H);

    if( ( xTimer1 != NULL ) && ( xTimer2 != NULL )&& ( xTimer3 != NULL )&& ( xTimer4 != NULL ) )
    {
        xTimer1Started = xTimerStart( xTimer1, 10 );
        xTimer2Started = xTimerStart( xTimer2, 10 );
        xTimer3Started = xTimerStart( xTimer3, 10 );
        xTimer4Started = xTimerStart( xTimer4, 10 );
    }
//  if( xTimer1 != NULL ) xTimer1Started = xTimerStart( xTimer1, 0 );
    if( xTimer1Started == pdPASS && xTimer2Started == pdPASS&& xTimer3Started == pdPASS&& xTimer4Started == pdPASS)
    {
        vTaskStartScheduler();
    }
//  if( xTimer1Started == pdPASS)vTaskStartScheduler();

    return 0;
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void Timer1Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore1 );
    //srand(time());
    Timer1Rand=(rand() % (UpperBound - LowerBound + 1)) + LowerBound;
    xTimerChangePeriod(xTimer1,pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer1Rand),0 );

//  vTaskResume(Task1H);
    //printf("A%d\n",Timer2Rand);


}
static void Timer2Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore2 );
    //srand(time());
    Timer2Rand=(rand() % (UpperBound - LowerBound + 1)) + LowerBound;
    xTimerChangePeriod(xTimer2,pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer2Rand),0 );

    //printf("B%d\n",Timer2Rand);
//  vTaskResume(Task2H);


}
static void Timer3Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore3 );
    //srand(time());
    Timer3Rand=(rand() % (UpperBound - LowerBound + 1)) + LowerBound;
    xTimerChangePeriod(xTimer3,pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer3Rand),0 );

    //printf("C%d\n",Timer3Rand);
   //vTaskResume(Task3H);


}
void Timer4Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore4 );

}
static void Sender1(void){

    while(1){
        if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore1, ( TickType_t ) 1   ) == pdTRUE){
            TotalTime1+=Timer1Rand;
            TimeTask1=xTaskGetTickCount();
            //printf("A%d\n",TimeTask1);
            itoa(TimeTask1,tickcount_converted,10);
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                    Message[8+i]=tickcount_converted[i];
                    }
            //printf("A%s\n",Message);

    if(xQueueSend(GlobalQueue,&Message,1 )==pdTRUE){
        NumberOfSent1++;}
    else NumberOfBlocked1++;
    printf("A%d\n",NumberOfSent1);
    //printf("AQ%d\n",NumberOfBlocked1);


        }}
}

static void Sender2(void){

    while(1){
        if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore2, ( TickType_t ) 1  ) == pdTRUE){
            TotalTime2+=Timer2Rand;
            TimeTask2=xTaskGetTickCount();
            itoa(TimeTask2,tickcount_converted,10);
                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                                Message[8+i]=tickcount_converted[i];
                                }
            if(xQueueSend(GlobalQueue,&Message,1 )==pdTRUE){
                    NumberOfSent2++;}
                else NumberOfBlocked2++;
            printf("B%d\n",NumberOfSent2);

    }}

}
static void Sender3(void){
    while(1){

        if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore3, ( TickType_t ) pdMS_TO_TICKS(10)  ) == pdTRUE){
            TotalTime3+=Timer3Rand;
            TimeTask3=xTaskGetTickCount();
            itoa(TimeTask3,tickcount_converted,10);
                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                                Message[8+i]=tickcount_converted[i];
                                }
        if(xQueueSend(GlobalQueue,&Message,1)==pdTRUE){
                NumberOfSent3++;}
            else NumberOfBlocked3++;
        printf("C%d\n",NumberOfSent3);

}

        }

}
void Receiver(void){

    while(1){
    if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore4, ( TickType_t ) 20  ) == pdTRUE){
        if(NumberOfReceived==1000){
            AverageTime1=TotalTime1/(NumberOfSent1+NumberOfBlocked1);
            AverageTime2=TotalTime2/(NumberOfSent2+NumberOfBlocked2);
            AverageTime3=TotalTime3/(NumberOfSent3+NumberOfBlocked3);
            printf("NumberOfSent1 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfSent1);
            printf("NumberOfBlocked1 in cycle %d= %d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfBlocked1);
            printf("Average 1 in cycle %d :%d\n",counterForCycle,AverageTime1);
            printf("NumberOfSent2 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfSent2);
            printf("NumberOfBlocked2 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfBlocked2);
            printf("AverageTime2 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,AverageTime2);
            printf("NumberOfSent3 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfSent3);
            printf("NumberOfBlocked3 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfBlocked3);
            printf("AverageTime3 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,AverageTime3);
            printf("NumberOfReceived in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfReceived);
            xQueueReset(GlobalQueue);
            counterForCycle++;
            TotalTime1=0;
            TotalTime2=0;
            TotalTime3=0;
            NumberOfSent1=0;
            NumberOfSent2=0;
            NumberOfSent3=0;
            NumberOfBlocked1=0;
            NumberOfBlocked2=0;
            NumberOfBlocked3=0;
            NumberOfReceived=0;
            UpperBound+=50;
            LowerBound+=30;

        }
        if(UpperBound>400){
            xTimerDelete(xTimer1,0);
            xTimerDelete(xTimer2,0);
            xTimerDelete(xTimer3,0);
            xTimerDelete(xTimer4,0);
            trace_puts("Game Over");
             vTaskEndScheduler();

        }
    if(xQueueReceive(GlobalQueue,Buffer,0 )==pdTRUE){
        NumberOfReceived++;
    }
   //printf("D%d\n",NumberOfReceived);

//
    printf("t%d\n",NumberOfReceived);


    }

}}
void vApplicationMallocFailedHook( void )
{
    /* Called if a call to pvPortMalloc() fails because there is insufficient
    free memory available in the FreeRTOS heap.  pvPortMalloc() is called
    internally by FreeRTOS API functions that create tasks, queues, software
    timers, and semaphores.  The size of the FreeRTOS heap is set by the
    configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE configuration constant in FreeRTOSConfig.h. */
    for( ;; );
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

void vApplicationStackOverflowHook( TaskHandle_t pxTask, char *pcTaskName )
{
    ( void ) pcTaskName;
    ( void ) pxTask;

    /* Run time stack overflow checking is performed if
    configconfigCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW is defined to 1 or 2.  This hook
    function is called if a stack overflow is detected. */
    for( ;; );
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

void vApplicationIdleHook( void )
{
volatile size_t xFreeStackSpace;

    /* This function is called on each cycle of the idle task.  In this case it
    does nothing useful, other than report the amout of FreeRTOS heap that
    remains unallocated. */
    xFreeStackSpace = xPortGetFreeHeapSize();

    if( xFreeStackSpace > 100 )
    {
        /* By now, the kernel has allocated everything it is going to, so
        if there is a lot of heap remaining unallocated then
        the value of configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE in FreeRTOSConfig.h can be
        reduced accordingly. */
    }
}

void vApplicationTickHook(void) {
}

StaticTask_t xIdleTaskTCB CCM_RAM;
StackType_t uxIdleTaskStack[configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE] CCM_RAM;

void vApplicationGetIdleTaskMemory(StaticTask_t **ppxIdleTaskTCBBuffer, StackType_t **ppxIdleTaskStackBuffer, uint32_t *pulIdleTaskStackSize) {
  /* Pass out a pointer to the StaticTask_t structure in which the Idle task's
  state will be stored. */
  *ppxIdleTaskTCBBuffer = &xIdleTaskTCB;

  /* Pass out the array that will be used as the Idle task's stack. */
  *ppxIdleTaskStackBuffer = uxIdleTaskStack;

  /* Pass out the size of the array pointed to by *ppxIdleTaskStackBuffer.
  Note that, as the array is necessarily of type StackType_t,
  configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE is specified in words, not bytes. */
  *pulIdleTaskStackSize = configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE;
}

static StaticTask_t xTimerTaskTCB CCM_RAM;
static StackType_t uxTimerTaskStack[configTIMER_TASK_STACK_DEPTH] CCM_RAM;

/* configUSE_STATIC_ALLOCATION and configUSE_TIMERS are both set to 1, so the
application must provide an implementation of vApplicationGetTimerTaskMemory()
to provide the memory that is used by the Timer service task. */
void vApplicationGetTimerTaskMemory(StaticTask_t **ppxTimerTaskTCBBuffer, StackType_t **ppxTimerTaskStackBuffer, uint32_t *pulTimerTaskStackSize) {
  *ppxTimerTaskTCBBuffer = &xTimerTaskTCB;
  *ppxTimerTaskStackBuffer = uxTimerTaskStack;
  *pulTimerTaskStackSize = configTIMER_TASK_STACK_DEPTH;
}
```

The sender task 3 is supposedly of higher prioirty but it acts the saem as the 2 other tasks in terms of msgs sent

Comment: A task's priority level doesn't affect how often it runs.

Comment: Shouldnt the higher priority task block the others when they send at the same time and this be able to send more msgs

Comment: The lower priority tasks may be delayed by a higher priority task, but they will still run and send the same messages.

Comment: @Abdelrahman sobhy, spaces are good: `3,32` looks like 3.32 in places that use a `,` as the decimal radix point.  Instead use `3, 32` (space added).